# Example repository to practice with Mylyn

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I am learning how to use Mylyn. I want to open Task-focused mode on Eclipse's Package Explor. However, the repository I got was bug tracking systems, which has no associated source code with it (or maybe I haven't figured out how to do it yet). I want to open something like in this screenshot:

[image: Task-focused mode on Eclipse's Package Explorer]

Do you have any repository which exposes code for me to view?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have code in an SCM (source code management) system. Local projects are just fine for playing around with Mylyn. Best to create Example projects (e.g. a plug-in project using some of the samples provided by Eclipse).

As for a task tracking system: the one that comes with Mylyn is the Eclipse bug tracker, so shouldn't be used to submit any test data. I would recommend setting up a connection to one of the repositories here: http://landfill.bugzilla.org/
You can create and submit tasks on those as you wish.

Good luck!